# SignalR Cross Domain with SSL

Tags: signalr

I have a website using SignalR to connect to a status hub that announces changes to some remote servers to all the connected clients.

I'm self hosting SignalR using OWIN and have enabled CORS allow all on the server.

When I use http hosting everything is fine.

As soon as I move to https with certificates everything grinds to a halt.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://10.141.114.79:8081//signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22statushub%22%7D%5D&_=1411656116180. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://10.141.114.79:453' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there something I'm missing about SignalR and SSL which prevents CORS from working in Chrome?

Edit - Added Cors and MapSignalR

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = false, EnableDetailedErrors = true, EnableJavaScriptProxies = false });
```

Comment: Can you provide the startup code where you call UseCors and MapSignalR?

Comment: Ever make any headway here?

Comment: No I never managed to solve it an ended up removing self hosting as an option so it ended up sharing the same port.  I would have liked to keep self host as an option but it just wasn't feasible.